# Suppressing GTK errors in Valgrind

Tags: c, gtk, valgrind, gnome

I am trying to write a GTK application and want to test its validity with valgrind.

This is an example program I want to test:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <gtk/gtk.h>

int
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  GtkWidget *win;
  GtkWidget *btn;

  gtk_init (&argc, &argv);

  win = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
  btn = gtk_button_new_with_label ("Hello");

  gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (win), btn);
  gtk_widget_show_all (win);

  gtk_main();
}
```

The GNOME Foundation wrote a [an article](https://wiki.gnome.org/Valgrind) about testing applications with valgrind, but even if I start valgrind with all this flags

```
valgrind --tool=memcheck --leak-check=full --num-callers=15 --log-file=vgdump ./diashow
```

or even with the [gtk.suppression file](https://people.gnome.org/~johan/gtk.suppression) mentioned on that valgrind-page

```
valgrind --tool=memcheck --leak-check=full --num-callers=15 --suppressions=gtk.suppression --log-file=vgdump ./diasho
```

the [valgrind dumpfile (pastebin)](http://pastebin.com/vbNihRex) `vgdump` is quite unreadable. 2285 lines!

The weirdest part for me is that my vgdump-file starts with `Invalid write of size 4` and then `Invalid read of size 4`. Can someone explain anything of that to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience a good rule when working with valgrind is to check a few errors at the beginning, try to fix these, and restart an app under valgrind again. The reason is: suppose you have an error in a function that allocates an array, and calls another function with the array and the size of the array+1 *(i.e. the size one element more of the real size)*. Then when the next function would try to access that excessive element, valgrind may notice it and trigger a warning. But the function may call another function, which may also try to access the element as well, which also leads to the warning, and so on.

So you end up with a bunch of messages that leads to a single error. And even if there's messages about another error, find these would usually be so hard, that it is easier to fix the first error, and restart app and valgrind again.

Also you need to take valgrind errors with a bit of skepticism. E.g. I remember it once reported to me about an uninitialized variable in a function main — for some reason valgrind couldn't see it actually is. It led to a message about an uninitialized variable usage in every function that main calls — i.e. every function in my program. But I should mention that it was long ago — three years ago — and I can suppose that the valgrind wasn't a recent version even back then just because Ubuntu repository tends to not have a latest versions of many apps.

The `Invalid read of size 4` means a buffer overflow somewhere. The stacktrace of the first such error should point where you could find the problem. It is hard to say more as you didn't show the stacktrace, but you have to know that the function with the error may be a victim of a wrong array from above.

As an aside note I'd advice you to debug that kind of errors [with AddressSanitizer](https://code.google.com/p/address-sanitizer/wiki/AddressSanitizer) which is available for both GCC and Clang by default *(and they have the same options to enable it)*. It tends to give a *much* more verbose output about an error *(yay, it is even colorful! ε:)*, and by default closes an app when any kind of memory error occurred. More over, valgrind misses most of memory errors when AddressSanitizer doesn't — such as stack overflows, and etc. Yes, sometimes *(as in your case)* it works, but from my experience aren't very often.

Comment: Thanks for your explaination. -- But I pasted the "stacktrace" (I think you mean the valgrind-warnings?) as the linked [pastebin-url](http://pastebin.com/vbNihRex).
The main question is: Why does gtk generate a stack overflow in such a trivial program?

Comment: @pausch ah, sorry, I mislooked it. Okay the stacktrace indeed aren't very helpful as I see. The question marks is functions somewhere in lib, which most probably a victim, but it is hard to say more. Okay, you know, just compile your application with `-g3 -fsanitize=address` options, next run it, and see, if it would fall. If it doesn't, then just ignore the warning *(skepticism, remember?)*, because I doesn't actually know a case when address sanitizer would miss an error which valgrind doesn't, but I've seen cases with false valgrind messages.

Comment: I tried these compile options, but after setting them (tested with gcc and clang) valgrind won't run: `Shadow memory range interleaves with an existing memory mapping. ASan cannot proceed correctly. ABORTING.`

Comment: @pausch hm… The page in faq mention a possible solution which may or may not work. Try running your app like `LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasan.so.0 ./myapp` *(but make sure where the library is before doing it. You can just run `locate asan` to list files with «asan» in names)*.

Comment: @pausch wait, I just reread your comment, did you say «valgrind won't run»? No, no, that's not what I meant — you have to launch the app compiled with the options without the valgrind. And if there are memory errors, the address sanitizer just would kill your app with error message. Otherwise I'd considered the valgrind messages to be false *(though to be sure I'd ask at valgrind mailing list)*

Comment: Very weird: I tried with `LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/libasan.so` because on my system the path you mentioned does not exist. But when executing `LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/libasan.so ./diashow` I get the message `Your application is linked against incompatible ASan runtimes.`

Comment: Yeah. That the previous error came from valgrind. See the following screenshots [Valgrind invocation with libasan](http://bit.ly/1BO3J9Y) +++ [Except from my Makefile, but changing clang to gcc doesn't change anything](http://bit.ly/1TXfVLp) ++++ [Invocation with LD_PRELOAD](http://bit.ly/1JrDlW8)

Comment: @pausch okay, calling with valgrind wouldn't make a sense here anyway. The error from LD_PRELOAD indeed weird. I'd try then to compile it by linking libasan statically, it could be done by adding in the  LDFLAGS `-Wl,-Bstatic -lasan -Wl,-Bdynamic`. But I have to mention it again: if the app compiled with address sanitizer works without valgrind — it is pretty much you need to know, here's no a reason in forcing it to work with valgrind.

Comment: Sorry about my lazyness: I didnt realize that `libasan` is that kind of AddressSanitizer you mentioned. So if I call my program which is compiled with these flags, libasan prints error messages if i have errors while accessing memory?

Comment: @pausch yes, it would print error, and next kill the app. In my experience it works for any kind of wrong memory access *(buffer overflow, access freed memory, etc…)*.

Comment: I just tested AddressSanitizer for a very dump minimal program with a memory error, and this works fine. It also works with just the `-fsanitize=address` option. Thank you! One last question: If valgrind reports errors in gtk which AddressSanitizer doesn't find, can I ignore the valgrind message then?

Comment: @pausch despite that everything okay, I'd anyway ask in valgrind mailing list to be sure. See: I am pretty sure that if there is an error in Gtk library itself, address sanitizer wouldn't say anything because it is not your app. But I don't remember how valgrind works, and theoretically I can suppose that errors aren't that false, but rather wrong memory access in the library itself. But it's just a thought, which may be wrong, and valgrind indeed sometimes reports false errors *(at least it often did in the past)* — that's why I'd ask anyway at their mailing list.

Comment: @pausch but answering, could you ignore it — yes, even if there are indeed error in the Gtk library itself, there's nothing you can do with it *(though, you can always download a source code, and help in development FOSS ;) )*.